# Function mod_scorm_insert_scorm_tracks "Invalid parameter"

Tags: php, rest, syntax-error, webservice-client, moodle-api

I have problem with a WebService function for moodle callen "**mod_scorm_insert_scorm_tracks**"

This function is used for inserting track information (i.e. star time) of a user in his SCORM progress.

Part of the estructure of this function is

```
scoid= int
attempt= int
tracks[0][element]= string
tracks[0][value]= string
```

**NEW**
PHP structe has to look like this

```
[tracks] =>
    Array 
        (
        [0] =>
            Array 
                (
                [element] => string                
                [value] => string                
                )
        )
```

---

I have used one of the examples they had in his website everything was fine until I got this error

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\otros\PHP-REST\curl.php</b> on line <b>247</b><br />
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<EXCEPTION class="invalid_parameter_exception">
<ERRORCODE>invalidparameter</ERRORCODE>
<MESSAGE>Invalid parameter value detected</MESSAGE>
<DEBUGINFO>tracks =&gt; Invalid parameter value detected: Only arrays accepted. The bad value is: 'Array'</DEBUGINFO>
</EXCEPTION>
```

And the problem seems to be here:

```
$item1 =  new stdClass();
$item1->scoid = '2';
$item1->attempt = '1';
$item1->tracks = array(
        array(
            array(
                'element' => 'x.start.time',
                'value' => '1473102672'
            ),
        ),
         array(
            array(
                'element' => 'x.start.time',
                'value' => '1473102680'
            ),
        ),
    );
```

I tried in many ways

```
$item1 =  new stdClass();
    $item1->scoid = '2';
    $item1->attempt = '1';
    $item1->tracks = array('element' => 'x.start.time','value' => '1473102672');
```

or

```
$item1 =  new stdClass();
    $item1->scoid = '2';
    $item1->attempt = '1';
    $item1->tracks = array(array ('element' => 'x.start.time','value' => '1473102672'));
```

And still getting the same message, I'm pretty that is problema with my wyntax but I have tried in many ways and still not working I hope yo can help me.

Complete Code:

```
/// SETUP - NEED TO BE CHANGED
$token = '481bf3d85a7eb539e37eabc88feccb3c';
$domainname = 'http://localhost/moodle';
//$functionname = 'mod_scorm_launch_sco';
$functionname = 'mod_scorm_insert_scorm_tracks';
//$functionname ='mod_scorm_view_scorm';

// REST RETURNED VALUES FORMAT
$restformat = 'xml'; //Also possible in Moodle 2.2 and later: 'json'
                     //Setting it to 'json' will fail all calls on earlier Moodle version


$item1 =  new stdClass();
$item1->scoid = '2';
$item1->attempt = '1';
$item1->tracks = array(
        array(
            array(
                'element' => 'x.start.time',
                'value' => 1473102672
            ),
        ),
         array(
            array(
                'element' => 'x.start.time',
                'value' => 1473102680
            ),
        ),
    );


$params = $item1;


/// REST CALL
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$serverurl = $domainname . '/webservice/rest/server.php'. '?wstoken=' . $token . '&wsfunction='.$functionname;
require_once('./curl.php');
$curl = new curl;
//if rest format == 'xml', then we do not add the param for backward compatibility with Moodle < 2.2
$restformat = ($restformat == 'json')?'&moodlewsrestformat=' . $restformat:'';
$resp = $curl->post($serverurl . $restformat, $params);
print_r($resp);
```

curl.php

```
<?php
/**
 * cURL class
 *
 * This is a wrapper class for curl, it is quite easy to use:
 * <code>
 * $c = new curl;
 * // enable cache
 * $c = new curl(array('cache'=>true));
 * // enable cookie
 * $c = new curl(array('cookie'=>true));
 * // enable proxy
 * $c = new curl(array('proxy'=>true));
 *
 * // HTTP GET Method
 * $html = $c->get('http://example.com');
 * // HTTP POST Method
 * $html = $c->post('http://example.com/', array('q'=>'words', 'name'=>'moodle'));
 * // HTTP PUT Method
 * $html = $c->put('http://example.com/', array('file'=>'/var/www/test.txt');
 * </code>
 *
 * @author     Dongsheng Cai <dongsheng@moodle.com> - https://github.com/dongsheng/cURL
 * @license    http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU Public License
 */

class curl {
    /** @var bool */
    public  $cache    = false;
    public  $proxy    = false;
    /** @var array */
    public  $response = array();
    public  $header   = array();
    /** @var string */
    public  $info;
    public  $error;

    /** @var array */
    private $options;
    /** @var string */
    private $proxy_host = '';
    private $proxy_auth = '';
    private $proxy_type = '';
    /** @var bool */
    private $debug    = false;
    private $cookie   = false;
    private $count    = 0;

    /**
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function __construct($options = array()){
        if (!function_exists('curl_init')) {
            $this->error = 'cURL module must be enabled!';
            trigger_error($this->error, E_USER_ERROR);
            return false;
        }
        // the options of curl should be init here.
        $this->resetopt();
        if (!empty($options['debug'])) {
            $this->debug = true;
        }
        if(!empty($options['cookie'])) {
            if($options['cookie'] === true) {
                $this->cookie = 'curl_cookie.txt';
            } else {
                $this->cookie = $options['cookie'];
            }
        }
        if (!empty($options['cache'])) {
            if (class_exists('curl_cache')) {
                $this->cache = new curl_cache();
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * Resets the CURL options that have already been set
     */
    public function resetopt(){
        $this->options = array();
        $this->options['CURLOPT_USERAGENT']         = 'MoodleBot/1.0';
        // True to include the header in the output
        $this->options['CURLOPT_HEADER']            = 0;
        // True to Exclude the body from the output
        $this->options['CURLOPT_NOBODY']            = 0;
        // TRUE to follow any "Location: " header that the server
        // sends as part of the HTTP header (note this is recursive,
        // PHP will follow as many "Location: " headers that it is sent,
        // unless CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS is set).
        //$this->options['CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION']    = 1;
        $this->options['CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS']         = 10;
        $this->options['CURLOPT_ENCODING']          = '';
        // TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return
        // value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
        $this->options['CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER']    = 1;
        $this->options['CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER']    = 0;
        $this->options['CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER']    = 0;
        $this->options['CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST']    = 2;
        $this->options['CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT']    = 30;
    }

    /**
     * Reset Cookie
     */
    public function resetcookie() {
        if (!empty($this->cookie)) {
            if (is_file($this->cookie)) {
                $fp = fopen($this->cookie, 'w');
                if (!empty($fp)) {
                    fwrite($fp, '');
                    fclose($fp);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set curl options
     *
     * @param array $options If array is null, this function will
     * reset the options to default value.
     *
     */
    public function setopt($options = array()) {
        if (is_array($options)) {
            foreach($options as $name => $val){
                if (stripos($name, 'CURLOPT_') === false) {
                    $name = strtoupper('CURLOPT_'.$name);
                }
                $this->options[$name] = $val;
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * Reset http method
     *
     */
    public function cleanopt(){
        unset($this->options['CURLOPT_HTTPGET']);
        unset($this->options['CURLOPT_POST']);
        unset($this->options['CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS']);
        unset($this->options['CURLOPT_PUT']);
        unset($this->options['CURLOPT_INFILE']);
        unset($this->options['CURLOPT_INFILESIZE']);
        unset($this->options['CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST']);
    }

    /**
     * Set HTTP Request Header
     *
     * @param array $headers
     *
     */
    public function setHeader($header) {
        if (is_array($header)){
            foreach ($header as $v) {
                $this->setHeader($v);
            }
        } else {
            $this->header[] = $header;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Set HTTP Response Header
     *
     */
    public function getResponse(){
        return $this->response;
    }
    /**
     * private callback function
     * Formatting HTTP Response Header
     *
     * @param mixed $ch Apparently not used
     * @param string $header
     * @return int The strlen of the header
     */
    private function formatHeader($ch, $header)
    {
        $this->count++;
        if (strlen($header) > 2) {
            list($key, $value) = explode(" ", rtrim($header, "\r\n"), 2);
            $key = rtrim($key, ':');
            if (!empty($this->response[$key])) {
                if (is_array($this->response[$key])){
                    $this->response[$key][] = $value;
                } else {
                    $tmp = $this->response[$key];
                    $this->response[$key] = array();
                    $this->response[$key][] = $tmp;
                    $this->response[$key][] = $value;

                }
            } else {
                $this->response[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        return strlen($header);
    }

    /**
     * Set options for individual curl instance
     *
     * @param object $curl A curl handle
     * @param array $options
     * @return object The curl handle
     */
    private function apply_opt($curl, $options) {
        // Clean up
        $this->cleanopt();
        // set cookie
        if (!empty($this->cookie) || !empty($options['cookie'])) {
            $this->setopt(array('cookiejar'=>$this->cookie,
                            'cookiefile'=>$this->cookie
                             ));
        }

        // set proxy
        if (!empty($this->proxy) || !empty($options['proxy'])) {
            $this->setopt($this->proxy);
        }
        $this->setopt($options);
        // reset before set options
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array(&$this,'formatHeader'));
        // set headers
        if (empty($this->header)){
            $this->setHeader(array(
                'User-Agent: MoodleBot/1.0',
                'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
                'Connection: keep-alive'
                ));
        }
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->header);

        if ($this->debug){
            echo '<h1>Options</h1>';
            var_dump($this->options);
            echo '<h1>Header</h1>';
            var_dump($this->header);
        }

        // set options
        foreach($this->options as $name => $val) {
            if (is_string($name)) {
                $name = constant(strtoupper($name));
            }
            curl_setopt($curl, $name, $val);
        }
        return $curl;
    }
    /**
     * Download multiple files in parallel
     *
     * Calls {@link multi()} with specific download headers
     *
     * <code>
     * $c = new curl;
     * $c->download(array(
     *              array('url'=>'http://localhost/', 'file'=>fopen('a', 'wb')),
     *              array('url'=>'http://localhost/20/', 'file'=>fopen('b', 'wb'))
     *              ));
     * </code>
     *
     * @param array $requests An array of files to request
     * @param array $options An array of options to set
     * @return array An array of results
     */
    public function download($requests, $options = array()) {
        $options['CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER'] = 1;
        $options['RETURNTRANSFER'] = false;
        return $this->multi($requests, $options);
    }
    /*
     * Mulit HTTP Requests
     * This function could run multi-requests in parallel.
     *
     * @param array $requests An array of files to request
     * @param array $options An array of options to set
     * @return array An array of results
     */
    protected function multi($requests, $options = array()) {
        $count   = count($requests);
        $handles = array();
        $results = array();
        $main    = curl_multi_init();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $url = $requests[$i];
            foreach($url as $n=>$v){
                $options[$n] = $url[$n];
            }
            $handles[$i] = curl_init($url['url']);
            $this->apply_opt($handles[$i], $options);
            curl_multi_add_handle($main, $handles[$i]);
        }
        $running = 0;
        do {
            curl_multi_exec($main, $running);
        } while($running > 0);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            if (!empty($options['CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER'])) {
                $results[] = true;
            } else {
                $results[] = curl_multi_getcontent($handles[$i]);
            }
            curl_multi_remove_handle($main, $handles[$i]);
        }
        curl_multi_close($main);
        return $results;
    }
    /**
     * Single HTTP Request
     *
     * @param string $url The URL to request
     * @param array $options
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function request($url, $options = array()){
        // create curl instance
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        $options['url'] = $url;
        $this->apply_opt($curl, $options);
        if ($this->cache && $ret = $this->cache->get($this->options)) {
            return $ret;
        } else {
            $ret = curl_exec($curl);
            if ($this->cache) {
                $this->cache->set($this->options, $ret);
            }
        }

        $this->info  = curl_getinfo($curl);
        $this->error = curl_error($curl);

        if ($this->debug){
            echo '<h1>Return Data</h1>';
            var_dump($ret);
            echo '<h1>Info</h1>';
            var_dump($this->info);
            echo '<h1>Error</h1>';
            var_dump($this->error);
        }

        curl_close($curl);

        if (empty($this->error)){
            return $ret;
        } else {
            return $this->error;
            // exception is not ajax friendly
            //throw new moodle_exception($this->error, 'curl');
        }
    }

    /**
     * HTTP HEAD method
     *
     * @see request()
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @param array $options
     * @return bool
     */
    public function head($url, $options = array()){
        $options['CURLOPT_HTTPGET'] = 0;
        $options['CURLOPT_HEADER']  = 1;
        $options['CURLOPT_NOBODY']  = 1;
        return $this->request($url, $options);
    }

    /**
     * Recursive function formating an array in POST parameter
     * @param array $arraydata - the array that we are going to format and add into &$data array
     * @param string $currentdata - a row of the final postdata array at instant T
     *                when finish, it's assign to $data under this format: name[keyname][][]...[]='value'
     * @param array $data - the final data array containing all POST parameters : 1 row = 1 parameter
     */
    function format_array_postdata_for_curlcall($arraydata, $currentdata, &$data) {
        foreach ($arraydata as $k=>$v) {
            $newcurrentdata = $currentdata;
            if (is_object($v)) {
                $v = (array) $v;
            }
            if (is_array($v)) { //the value is an array, call the function recursively
                $newcurrentdata = $newcurrentdata.'['.urlencode($k).']';
                $this->format_array_postdata_for_curlcall($v, $newcurrentdata, $data);
            }  else { //add the POST parameter to the $data array
                $data[] = $newcurrentdata.'['.urlencode($k).']='.urlencode($v);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Transform a PHP array into POST parameter
     * (see the recursive function format_array_postdata_for_curlcall)
     * @param array $postdata
     * @return array containing all POST parameters  (1 row = 1 POST parameter)
     */
    function format_postdata_for_curlcall($postdata) {
        if (is_object($postdata)) {
            $postdata = (array) $postdata;
        }
        $data = array();
        foreach ($postdata as $k=>$v) {
            if (is_object($v)) {
                $v = (array) $v;
            }
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $currentdata = urlencode($k);
                $this->format_array_postdata_for_curlcall($v, $currentdata, $data);
            }  else {
                $data[] = urlencode($k).'='.urlencode($v);
            }
        }
        $convertedpostdata = implode('&', $data);
        return $convertedpostdata;
    }

    /**
     * HTTP POST method
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @param array|string $params
     * @param array $options
     * @return bool
     */
    public function post($url, $params = '', $options = array()){
        $options['CURLOPT_POST']       = 1;
        if (is_array($params)) {
            $params = $this->format_postdata_for_curlcall($params);
        } 
        $options['CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS'] = $params;
        return $this->request($url, $options);
    }

    /**
     * HTTP GET method
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @param array $params
     * @param array $options
     * @return bool
     */
    public function get($url, $params = array(), $options = array()){
        $options['CURLOPT_HTTPGET'] = 1;

        if (!empty($params)){
            $url .= (stripos($url, '?') !== false) ? '&' : '?';
            $url .= http_build_query($params, '', '&');
        }
        return $this->request($url, $options);
    }

    /**
     * HTTP PUT method
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @param array $params
     * @param array $options
     * @return bool
     */
    public function put($url, $params = array(), $options = array()){
        $file = $params['file'];
        if (!is_file($file)){
            return null;
        }
        $fp   = fopen($file, 'r');
        $size = filesize($file);
        $options['CURLOPT_PUT']        = 1;
        $options['CURLOPT_INFILESIZE'] = $size;
        $options['CURLOPT_INFILE']     = $fp;
        if (!isset($this->options['CURLOPT_USERPWD'])){
            $this->setopt(array('CURLOPT_USERPWD'=>'anonymous: noreply@moodle.org'));
        }
        $ret = $this->request($url, $options);
        fclose($fp);
        return $ret;
    }

    /**
     * HTTP DELETE method
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @param array $params
     * @param array $options
     * @return bool
     */
    public function delete($url, $param = array(), $options = array()){
        $options['CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST'] = 'DELETE';
        if (!isset($options['CURLOPT_USERPWD'])) {
            $options['CURLOPT_USERPWD'] = 'anonymous: noreply@moodle.org';
        }
        $ret = $this->request($url, $options);
        return $ret;
    }
    /**
     * HTTP TRACE method
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @param array $options
     * @return bool
     */
    public function trace($url, $options = array()){
        $options['CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST'] = 'TRACE';
        $ret = $this->request($url, $options);
        return $ret;
    }
    /**
     * HTTP OPTIONS method
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @param array $options
     * @return bool
     */
    public function options($url, $options = array()){
        $options['CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST'] = 'OPTIONS';
        $ret = $this->request($url, $options);
        return $ret;
    }
    public function get_info() {
        return $this->info;
    }
}

/**
 * This class is used by cURL class, use case:
 *
 * <code>
 *
 * $c = new curl(array('cache'=>true), 'module_cache'=>'repository');
 * $ret = $c->get('http://www.google.com');
 * </code>
 *
 * @package    core
 * @subpackage file
 * @copyright  1999 onwards Martin Dougiamas  {@link http://moodle.com}
 * @license    http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU GPL v3 or later
 */
class curl_cache {
    /** @var string */
    public $dir = '';
    /**
     *
     * @param string @module which module is using curl_cache
     *
     */
    function __construct() {
        $this->dir = '/tmp/';
        if (!file_exists($this->dir)) {
            mkdir($this->dir, 0700, true);
        }
        $this->ttl = 1200;
    }

    /**
     * Get cached value
     *
     * @param mixed $param
     * @return bool|string
     */
    public function get($param){
        $this->cleanup($this->ttl);
        $filename = 'u_'.md5(serialize($param));
        if(file_exists($this->dir.$filename)) {
            $lasttime = filemtime($this->dir.$filename);
            if(time()-$lasttime > $this->ttl)
            {
                return false;
            } else {
                $fp = fopen($this->dir.$filename, 'r');
                $size = filesize($this->dir.$filename);
                $content = fread($fp, $size);
                return unserialize($content);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Set cache value
     *
     * @param mixed $param
     * @param mixed $val
     */
    public function set($param, $val){
        $filename = 'u_'.md5(serialize($param));
        $fp = fopen($this->dir.$filename, 'w');
        fwrite($fp, serialize($val));
        fclose($fp);
    }

    /**
     * Remove cache files
     *
     * @param int $expire The number os seconds before expiry
     */
    public function cleanup($expire){
        if($dir = opendir($this->dir)){
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
                if(!is_dir($file) && $file != '.' && $file != '..') {
                    $lasttime = @filemtime($this->dir.$file);
                    if(time() - $lasttime > $expire){
                        @unlink($this->dir.$file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * delete current user's cache file
     *
     */
    public function refresh(){
        if($dir = opendir($this->dir)){
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
                if(!is_dir($file) && $file != '.' && $file != '..') {
                    if(strpos($file, 'u_')!==false){
                        @unlink($this->dir.$file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a custom `curl` class?

Comment: yes, is in other php file.

Comment: Please provide the code.

Comment: I _think_ at some point in `format_postdata_for_curlcall` or `format_array_postdata_for_curlcall`you are unintentionally casting your param array to a string, which would give the string "Array`. Unfortunately I don't have time to go through debugging where it happens.

Comment: Thanks I will look this functions and see what happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after some research I finally took plan B

I wrote tracks in a different variable:

```
$tracks = array();
        $tracks[] = array(
            'element' => 'cmi.core.lesson_status',
            'value' => 'completed'
        );
```

And I followed curl.php array set option:

```
$arrayName = array('' => , );
```

Then when I inserted scoid and attemps as single variables in the array:

```
$params = array('scoid' => '2', 'attempt' => '1', 'tracks' => $tracks);
```

and boala!the record is on my table:

[image: Inserted record]